# How can I have two routes that use the same Method using C# WebAPI 2

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, routes, asp.net-web-api2

I'm using C# With a Web API 2 project.  I want a controller that has a function that contains two possible routes for the same Method.  If size isn't set, I want it to pass null.  So far I've tried:

```
public class PController : ApiController
{
    [Route("~/personphoto/{id:Guid}")]
    [Route("~/personphoto/{id:Guid}/sizes/{string:size}")]
    [AllowHeaderFilter(HttpMethodFlag.Get)]
    public IHttpActionResult GetPhoto(Guid id, string size)
    {
        // Do Something
    }
}
```

Is this possible?

Comment: What is problem with `[Route("~/personphoto/{id:Guid}/sizes/{string:size}")]` route? If you do not want to pass size then pass it as null. Is there any specific reason you want to create two routes.

Comment: I wanted to create one route that assigns a default size, so you don't have to put sizes/{size} in

Answer (score 0):

I believe this is what you're looking for:

```
[Route("~/personphoto/{id:Guid}/{sizes?}/{size?}")]
public IHttpActionResult GetPhoto(Guid id, string sizes = "", string size = "")
```

Comment: I guess "sizes" is a string literal, not a parameter, in op case.